# ocilogon(): ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred

Tags: php, oci8

my configuration:

**PHP**

PHP 5.4.16

**OCI8**

OCI8 Support    enabled
OCI8 DTrace Support     disabled
OCI8 Version    2.0.11

**Environment**

LANG    C

PATH    /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/instantclient

NOTIFY_SOCKET   /run/systemd/notify

ORACLE_HOME     /opt/instantclient

LD_LIBRARY_PATH     /opt/instantclient

TNS_ADMIN   /opt/instantclient/network/admin

XERCES_DISABLE_DTD  1

**firewall**

disable

**issue**

when i execute a php page with ocilogon:

ocilogon(): ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred

but if i try telnet xxxx 1521 i can connect to the Db

my php code:

```
$test1 = "(DESCRIPTION =
         (ADDRESS_LIST =
         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxxxxx)(PORT = 1521))
         )
         (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = yyy))
         )";

$conn=ocilogon(USERNAME,PASSWORD,$test1) or die ("logon problem");
```

i tryed with oci_connect, same result.

Comment: Check SQL*Plus can connect.  Your error points to a network configuration issue, possibly a in-bound or out-bound firewall.

Comment: Some general FYI comments: (i) because you are using Instant Client you don't need to set ORACLE_HOME (ii) you are using obsolete function names in PHP. The new ones are like oci_connect() (iii) you can use the 'easy connect' syntax instead of that old, full TNS string.  The new syntax is  like `$test = "xxxxxx/yyy"`. Check Oracle's free book on PHP OCI8: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html

Comment: ty for your comment Christopher. 
As i say before, i tried with oci_connect, same result.

Comment: and firewalld or selinux are disable.
If i try telnet xxxx 1521 i don't have any problem, i login into oracle db

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

i tried to connect to a oracle rac with 5 different ip. My network admin allow only 4 of 5.

So network issue, with tcpdump we find the problem.

thanks